# How to set validation check in ViewModel

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am newbie in building javafx MVVM app.
I've created a simple ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel {
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final IntegerProperty age = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public PersonViewModel() {}

    // getters and setters
}
```

and simple View:

```
public class PersonView implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    TextField name;

    @FXML
    TextField age;

    @FXML
    Button ok;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        PersonViewModel viewModel = new PersonViewModel();
        name.textProperty().bindBidirectional(viewModel.name);
        age.textProperty().bindBidirectional(viewModel.age);
    }
}
```

Can you give me any idea how to make age validation? F.e. I wanna not to allow user to put characters into age (TextField) except [a-zA-Z]. And the main idea of my question to make this validation in ViewModel) Help me pls.

P.S. I wanna make it not using not standard javafx components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `TextFormatter` both to filter input in a text input control, and to convert the text into a value of a specific type. If you want the view model to define the validation rules, then define a method in there representing the validation, and delegate to that method in the filter definition for the `TextFormatter`. For example:

```
public class PersonViewModel {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }
    public final String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty.set(name);
    }

    private final IntegerProperty age = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
        return age ;
    }
    public final int getAge() {
        return ageProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setAge(int age) {
        ageProperty.set(age);
    }

    public boolean validAgeInput(String input) {
        // must support partial entry while editing, including empty string
        // accept any integer from 0 - 135 (arbitrary upper bound example)
        String regex = "([0-9]{0,2})|(1[0-2][0-9])|(13[0-5])";
        return input.matches(regex);
    }

}
```

Now you can do:

```
public class PersonView implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    TextField name;

    @FXML
    TextField age;

    @FXML
    Button ok;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        PersonViewModel viewModel = new PersonViewModel();
        UnaryOperator<Change> filter = change -> {
            if (viewModel.validAgeInput(change.getControlNewText()) {
                // accept
                return change ;
            } else {
                // reject
                return null ;
            }
        };
        TextFormatter<Integer> ageFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(new IntegerStringConverter(), 0, filter);
        age.setTextFormatter(ageFormatter);
        ageFormatter.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(viewModel.ageProperty().asObject());
        name.textProperty().bindBidirectional(viewModel.nameProperty());
    }
}
```

The filter defined here will only accept input in the control if it matches the rule defined by the method in the `PersonViewModel`. The `valueProperty()` of the `TextFormatter` represents the text in the `TextField` after passing it to the `IntegerStringConverter`: this is bound bidirectionally to the `ageProperty()` in the model. (The call to `asObject()` effectively just converts between an `IntegerProperty` and an `ObjectProperty<Integer>`.)